# How to enable "Take a quick photo" option during chats in Smooch SDK for SWIFT?

Tags: swift, permissions, info.plist, smooch

I'm using Smooch SDK for adding chat feature to my iOS application.

According to its [documentation](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/native-ios-sdk/#customization), it suggests to add below keys to `Info.plist` to allow users send photos or capture photos from camera.

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} will read your photo library to gather additional information</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} will write to your photo library to gather additional information</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} will use your camera to gather additional information</string>
```

However when I try to send items during chat, only "Photo & Video Library" and "Upload Document" is enabled and "Take a Quick Photo" is not  present.

Do I need to do more actions to enable "Take a Quick Photo" option?

Comment: Are you using the iOS simulator or a physical device? The take quick photo option is not available on the simulator as there is no camera

Comment: @michaels I'm using a physical device and this option is not available.

Comment: And your code is not modifying `SKTSettings.allowedMenuItems` right?

Comment: @michaels I also tried to use allowedMenuItems to force take quick photo option but situation did not change.

Comment: Can you let me know the result of these three operations? `[UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]`, `[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"NSCameraUsageDescription"] != nil`, and `[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription"] != nil`. They should all evaluate to `true`

Comment: @michaels thank you for your reponse. The problem was the fact that I was using `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` key instead of  `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription`

Comment: @michaels please post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, for the "Take a Quick Photo" to appear, the following conditions must all evaluate to `true`

```
[UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"NSCameraUsageDescription"] != nil
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription"] != nil
```

Additionally, the `SKTSettings.allowedMenuItems` array must include an entry for `SKTMenuItemCamera` (this is enabled by default)